# JSF 2.2 content not rendered until page refreshed

Tags: jsf-2

I am loading stuff via AJAX into my JSF page from the server. However, not all of the content is displayed immediately, two divs arent displayed until the page is refreshed.

Here's the form for loading the content:

```
            <h:form>
                <h:dataTable value="#{consoleController.list}" var="item">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:commandLink class="list-group-item"
                            action="#{consoleController.defineLink()}">#{item}
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{consoleController.content}"
                                value="#{item}" />
                            <f:ajax event="action" render="menuDiv contenDiv facetDiv"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

These are the elements I want to load the code into.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h:panelGroup id="menuDiv">
            <ui:include src="#{consoleController.loadMenu()}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h:panelGroup id="contentDiv">
            <ui:include src="#{consoleController.loadPage()}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="facetDiv">
            <ui:include src="#{consoleController.loadFacet()}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

`menuDiv` is displayed fine, the other two aren't displayed until I refresh the page.

What's the problem here?

I read that you cannot upload elements that don't exist in the JSF tree, but that's not the case here.

Comment: What happens if you change your `#{consoleController.loadPage()}` for a static ui view? Anyway, if this is some new development, I encourage you going with faces templates instead, they provide more flexibility and are much less problematic in general.

Comment: @BalusC not really, since I am not including template.xhtml files but html files that get uploaded by the users and I cannot put those into the WEB-INF folder. But anyway, there must be a way to load three components at once via ajax. Why exactly isn't it working here? Or rather: Why is it only working for one of the panels?

Comment: @BalusC the pages I include do contain h:form elements. Is that the problem?`I don't really know which aspects of your answer to that post apply to my problem.

Comment: @BalusC I am not setting the page in a getter...? Where do you see that? And ViewScoped doesnt work for me, I need session scope. But I got it to work, see my answer.

Comment: Ah right. So you suggest passing the parameter directly via the method specified in the action attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it was as easy as removing the h:form tag around the last panel tag:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="facetDiv">
            <ui:include src="#{consoleController.loadFacet()}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

becomes:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <h:panelGroup id="facetDiv">
            <ui:include src="#{consoleController.loadFacet()}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

and now it works.

Comment: @BalusC I havent prefixed the IDs with : and it still works. Why is that? And what do you mean a God Form?